# Magit show git hook output

Tags: magit, git

I'd like to configure magit so that when I decide to commit my changes I'm shown not only the buffer to edit commit message and the diff of changes but also the magit-process buffer. Is there a way of doing that?

This would help me with my git repos where I have pre-commit hooks defined that return some useful info but don't block the commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using those settings:

```
(setq magit-diff-auto-show nil) ;; This should be the defult IMHO
(add-hook 'server-switch-hook 'magit-process)
```

The only problem I got left is that the focus ends in my process buffer and it's not easy (using `switch-to-buffer` or `other-window`) to get back to commit message in the hook, as it's messing with the emacs-client that's being used here.

Still this is good enough for me as now I see the output of *pre-commit hook* when editing the message.

**Edit**

Following Iqbal's comment I changed my solution to:

```
(setq magit-diff-auto-show nil)
(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook (lambda () (save-selected-window (magit-process))))
```

which works as a charm!

Comment: You can wrap the call to `magit-process` in  `save-selected-window` macro and add it to `server-switch-hook` like so `(add-hook 'server-switch-hook (lambda () (save-selected-window (magit-process))))` . But your solution isn't cleanest since `server-switch-hook` is not magit specific can be called in other circumstances

Comment: `git-commit-mode-hook` might be more appropriate for your purpose

Comment: fyi, this breaks latest magit since magit-process no longer exists - see https://github.com/magit/with-editor/issues/61