# Write function that runs a command only after a previous command finishes

Tags: magit

I would like to create a function that runs a command only after a previous command that takes some input from the user finishes running. In particular, I would like to write a function that runs a command after magit-pull:

```
(defun test ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'magit-pull)
  (read-key)
  (command)
)
```

The above function works only when magit-pull does not ask me for a password. However, when magit-pull asks me to enter my password in the minibufer, the above code won't work. I suppose I need to add some code that will only run "command" only after magit-pull is finished. Does anyone know of how I can implement this?

Comment: Add an advice to magic-pull.  Check if there is a magit-pull-hook?

Comment: @John Kitchin : I didn't find a magit-pull-hook but, as expected, magit has other hooks available that I might try using. How would you use a hook in this case?

Comment: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16558/7045

Comment: @EmacsUser : if I understood your suggestion correctly, adding something to a magit hook with 'add-hook' seems to have uninted consequences. For instance, with '(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook  (lambda () (command)))' would run 'command' every time you enter or leave git-commit-mode.

Comment: Generally speaking, tools to accomplish this objective are in the nature of a process sentinel and/or `recursive-edit`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237869/fine-tuning-set-process-sentinel-set-process-filter-start-process  In terms of `magit-pull`, I'll leave that for Tarsius or another forum participant.

Comment: If there is no magit-pull-hook then it is not likely another hook would work for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623208/how-to-execute-a-command-right-after-a-fetch-or-pull-command-in-git for a way to setup a git hook function that will probably work for you.

Comment: I suspect the real problem here is that magit-pull is calling some asynchronous code. I don't think it should matter whether or not the user is prompted for input. If the code is synchronous, the subsequent commands won't run until after the user makes their input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution to "do something after another command" is to use advice, as suggested in the comments above.

```
(defun after-magit-pull ()
  "Some function to run after `magit-pull`.")
  (whatever))

(advice-add 'magit-pull :after 'after-magit-pull)
```

Whether this is the best way to accomplish your goal is a slightly different question. Using a git hook may be more appropriate, again as noted in the comments.

*Update*

Looking at `magit-pull` a bit more, using advice does not seem appropriate for this particular case. Magit starts git processes asynchronously and uses `magit-process-sentinel` to wait for the git process to complete so that it can do some additional work (like refreshing buffers). So `:after` advice on a command like `magit-pull` will probably run before the underlying git process actually completes.

To take some action after a git command finishes you might be able to use the `magit-post-refresh-hook`. I haven't tried this, but you could create your own command that adds an additional function to the post-refresh hook -- one that removes itself when it is done -- and then calling `magit-pull`.

Comment: My understanding is that this will advise `magit-pull` every time I call it. I guess I could use `advice-remove` at the end of the function to change that.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something stupid, the code above works when instead of using `magit-pull` I use an non-interactive function (e.g., `bury-buffer`). Do I need to change anything when using `advice-add` to apply to interactive functions?

Comment: The command `bury-buffer` is also interactive -- in elisp any command you can invoke via `M-x` is interactive, and advice works in either case. However, `magit-pull` is a bit more complicated: magit is starting git processes, sometimes asynchronously. In that case advice is not appropriate because the advised function will finish before the external git process returns.